# Merge array of objects by same key in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I got below array of object from response

```
[{
"pagination":
  {
    "count": 1
  },
"products": [
  {
    "createdBy": "user1",
    "status": 1,
  }
 ]
},
{
"pagination": {
  "count": 3
},
"products": [
  {
    "createdBy": "user2",
    "status": 2,
  },
  {
    "createdBy": "user3",
    "status": 3,
  }
  ]
}
}
]
```

I want to merge objects of array by keys - products and pagination. I want my final output to be like in below format

```
{
 "products": [
  {
   "createdBy": "user1",
   "status": 1,
   },
 {
   "createdBy": "user2",
    "status": 2,
  },
 {
   "createdBy": "user3",
   "status": 3,
 }
]
}
```

Kindly help how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const array = [
    {
        "pagination": {
            "count": 1
        },
        "products": [
            {
                "createdBy": "user1",
                "status": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pagination": {
            "count": 3
        },
        "products": [
            {
                "createdBy": "user2",
                "status": 2
            },
            {
                "createdBy": "user3",
                "status": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]

const result = array.reduce((tempArray,res)=>{
tempArray.push(...res.products)
    return tempArray;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out (where arr is your input array)

```
function getProducts() {
const newArr = arr.map(el => {
    return el.products;
})  
return {
  products: newArr.flat()
}
}

getProducts();
```